# Understanding iptables logs with openvpn

Tags: openvpn, iptables, forwarding

I have configured an openvpn server (Debian 10) to access a webserver on my local network, everything works as it should, but looking at the iptables log I don't understand one thing.
This is how I set up the Iptables:

```
192.168.0.42 = Web-server ip
192.168.0.21 (Current host) = VPN Server ip
10.8.0.6 = Virtual IP address of the remote client (VPN)
```

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
...

-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT



*mangle
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
...

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.21 -s 192.168.0.42 -j MARK --set-mark 10 

-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix "[iptables-post] "    --log-prefix 4
-A INPUT       -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix "[iptables-input] "   --log-prefix 4
-A PREROUTING  -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix "[iptables-pre] "     --log-prefix 4
-A OUTPUT      -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix "[iptables-out] "     --log-prefix 4
-A FORWARD     -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix "[iptables-forward] " --log-prefix 4
COMMIT
```

As a result, I tracked the marked packet (10) coming from the web server to my vpn server (and back to client) and this is how it goes through Iptables:

```
*mangle

PREROUTING:        =>     FORWARD:           =>      POSTROUTING:
SRC=192.168.0.42          SRC=192.168.0.42           SRC=192.168.0.42
DST=192.168.0.21          DST=10.8.0.6               DST=10.8.0.6
IN =enp0s3                IN =enp0s3                 IN =
OUT=                      OUT=tun0                   OUT=tun0
```

I do not understand where the packet will go after the **POSTROUTING** chain, because the destination address is **10.8.0.6**, the server does not know where to redirect it, or does it know where to redirect the packet with the destination address **10.8.0.6**? If so, how does the server know this?

Similarly with the **FORWARD** chain, why did it change from destination address **192.168.0.21** to **10.8.0.6**? Shouldn't it have been redirected to INPUT? because the destination address is **192.168.0.21** - This is the address of the current host (VPN). The last question: Why does the request from the web server only go to the **FORWARD** chain? Shouldn't the VPN server encrypt the data before transmitting it to the client? I do not quite understand this, I have been looking for answers for a long time, but I still have not found an answer, I will be very glad if someone can help figure it out.

This is what my routing table looks like:

```
Destination     Gateway        Genmask          Iface

default         192.168.0.1    0.0.0.0          enp0s3
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2       255.255.255.0    tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0        255.255.255.255  tun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0    enp0s3
```

OpenVPN server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  
dh dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.0.42 255.255.255.255"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
   tls-version-min 1.3
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA256
max-clients 2
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
explicit-exit-notify 0
tcp-queue-limit 256
```

Comment: `I do not understand where the packet will go after the POSTROUTING chain...` it will go out of `tun0`, where OpenVPN will take over the job. `how` you have a `10.8.0.0/24` route with `tun0` being its interface (`gateway` is bogus and optional for a `tun` route btw.)

Comment: `Similarly with the FORWARD chain, why did it change from destination address 192.168.0.21 to 10.8.0.6?` Probably because the traffic is a reply for a traffic that was SNAT'd (`MASQUERADE`), so the reply has the forwarder/server's LAN IP as destination. Netfilter/iptables will then perform "reverse NAT" automatically so that the reply will go to its real but "hidden" "client"/"target" host. It can do so because it keep tracks of all the NAT'ing.

Comment: `Why does the request from the web server only go to the FORWARD chain?` Essentially whether traffics from other hosts go into `FORWARD` instead of `INPUT` is based on whether the destination addresses (after the aforementioned "reverse NAT") is one of the addresses configured on the forwarder itself.

Comment: Note that the VPN / encryption covers only the path between the VPN client and the VPN server. Say client A visits a website via the VPN server, the transmission between the web server and the VPN server is NOT covered/encrypted by the VPN *unless* the web server itself is also one of the VPN clients (and the tunnel is the path to use that is picked with routing for this part). (OpenVPN has its own `client-to-client` approach which does not involve the network stack of the server though.)

Comment: Thank you very much @TomYan , I know that the traffic between the web server and the VPN server is not encrypted, but when a response comes from the web server to the client via the VPN server, openVPN has to encrypt the data and transmit it to the client, right? Does the server encrypt data in the openVPN application? To do this, the data packet must enter the application via the INPUT chain. Do I get it right !?:)

Comment: `openVPN has to encrypt the data and transmit it to the client` yeah unless you are using some encryption-less openvpn setup. `Does the server encrypt data in the openVPN application?` Anything that go out of the tunnel interface (that OpenVPN knows a client to send to / what to do with it) will be encrypted by OpenVPN (the program).  `To do this, the data packet must enter the application via the INPUT chain.` No, if it ends up in `INPUT` it essentially means it will NOT go to another host. `FORWARD` is "bi-directional", if that's what you are wondering.

Comment: Then the last question, where does openVPN encrypt traffic coming from the web server to the client and vice versa? In the FORWARD chain?

Comment: None of the chains. More precisely, it's pretty much an invalid question. iptables/Netfilter has nothing to do with OpenVPN but the kernel. By the time openvpn takes over the job, the traffics would have gone through the whole Netfilter framework (or even the whole network stack). (Well, in terms of the non-capsulated scope.) Imagine the OpenVPN program to be a host / endpoint of the tunnel interface, what goes out of the interface get received by the (userspace) program and is handled (encapsulated and encrypted) by it. It's just the program is actually on the same host, as if it's "nested".

Comment: Then the encapsulated and encrypted packet is sent out to the global/public address of corresponding client by the program. It will certainly go through `OUTPUT` and so. But that's a whole different context now.

Comment: By the way that's at least part of the reason why `gateway` is bogus and optional for the `tun` route(s): the OpenVPN program is always the actual "gateway" if you compare it to Ethernet.

Comment: @TomYan You are an angel. Now everything became clear to me. I drew diagrams on paper, read the documentation, and still did not fully understand. Thank you very much, you are a wonderful person and an expert in your field.